# How can I run a package setup only once?

Tags: package-development

I'm writing a package to interact with a web service via HTTP API. But I need to make an action once to get permission to send my data. This action must be made just one time.
How can I configure my package to run this `setup` function only once after installed?

Comment: Do you want to run it after uninstall and reinstall? What about package update?

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to save this information somewhere persistently.

You might write data to a package-specific config file (see `locate-user-emacs-file`), but the simplest approach is probably to use `defcustom` to define an option indicating whether or not the setup has been completed, and to call `(customize-save-variable 'VARNAME VALUE)` in your code once setup is complete.

I'm assuming that the setup isn't *already* creating variable values that you could test for.